# Maintaining an array under subarray reversals

Tags: data-structures

Given a sequence of real numbers $\{a_1, a_2, a_3 \ldots a_n\}$, I wish to design a data structure that supports the following operations on it.

1. $\mathrm{REVERSE}(i,j):$ Reverse the contiguous subsequence $a_i, a_{i+1}\ldots a_j$ i.e. swap $a_i$ with $a_j$, $a_{i+1}$ with $a_{j-1}$ so on and so forth.
2. $\mathrm{REPORT}(i):$ Report the $i$-th element of the sequence.

In my attempt so far I have tried to construct a binary tree each node of which maintains a composition of reversals of the underlying segment but it doesn't seem like this approach can work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/treap.html#implicit-treaps

Answer (score 2):

You can get both operations in $O(\log n)$ time with a binary tree. The idea is to store a boolean at each node indicating whether or not the entire subtree underneath the node is logically (not physically) reversed. You can then reverse a node in $O(1)$, by toggling the boolean.

Logical reversal is pretty easy to handle: any time you would descend into a node, check if the node is marked as reversed; if so, then swap and logically reverse its children.

Using this approach, we can adapt standard split/join primitives. And then, using split/join, we can implement `REVERSE(i,j)` like this:

1. split at offsets `i` and `j` to produce three trees `left`, `middle`, and `right`,
2. logically reverse `middle` by toggling the boolean at its root, and
3. join the three trees.

This requires only $O(\log n)$ time on a balanced tree.

---

Here's some pseudocode. The implementation of `REPORT` should hopefully demonstrate how logical reversal is handled.

```
// elements of type T
type Tree<T> {
  elem: T,
  left: Tree<T>,
  right: Tree<T>,
  size: int,
  rev: bool
}


function TOGGLE(tree) {
  tree.rev = !(tree.rev);
  return tree;
}


// swap and toggle children, if necessary. O(1) time.
function NORMALIZE(tree) {
  if (tree.rev) {
    left = tree.left;
    right = tree.right;
    
    tree.left = TOGGLE(right);
    tree.right = TOGGLE(left);
    tree.rev = False;
  }
}


function REPORT(tree, i) {
  NORMALIZE(tree);

  if (i <= tree.left.size)
    return REPORT(tree.left, i);
  else if (i == tree.left.size + 1)
    return tree.elem;
  else
    return REPORT(tree.right, i - tree.left.size - 1);
}


function REVERSE(tree, i, j) {
  left, tmp = SPLIT(tree, i);
  middle, right = SPLIT(tmp, j-i+1);
  return JOIN(left, JOIN(TOGGLE(middle), right))
}


function SPLIT(tree, i) { /* omitted... */ }
function JOIN(tree1, tree2) { /* omitted... */ }
```